# Парсер забирает текст, но не выводит его в консоль

Tags: python, html, requests, beautiful-soup

Код:

```
def g():
    r = requests.get()






def get_page_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    trs = soup.find_all('tr')
    
    for tr2 in trs:     # Попытка забрать время
        try:
            tds2 = tr2.find_all('td', class_='first time')
            name = tds2[0].find('td').text
        except:
            name = ''

        print(name)
```

Менял теги поиска, обращался к разным записям в списке `trs`, все равно в консоли пусто...
Тогда возникает вопрос этот текст присутсвует или нет?
Можно текст дальше использовать в работе или нет?

Comment: Так вы посмотрите, что в `soup.html` получается. Там туча скриптов. Скорее всего нужное вам содержимое генерится через `java script` и нужно использовать `Selenium`.

Comment: А, как посмотреть soup.html не до конца понимаю, что это? Посмотрел XHR Get запросы там одна запись, получает гиф картинку. Ранее забирал на прямую(без работы с джава) другой текст с таблицы ('div', id='center') и ссылки, все удачно. Но обратится к столбцу со временем не удается... Селениум пока не могу использовать, хочу сначала с "реквест и суп" более имение разобраться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что-то вы намудрили там ;)
Моя "Попытка забрать время":

```
for tr in trs:     # Попытка забрать время
    tr_time = tr.find('td', class_='first time')
    if tr_time:
        print(tr_time.text[:5])
```

прекрасно выводит время, если оно есть в строке:

```
--:--
03:10
03:10

...

16:00 
16:00
```

PS периодически проскакивают такие: `16:00Live streamsbet365bwin`, нужно найти откуда и скорректировать код

**UPD** формат часы:минуты везде одинаковый, поэтому просто [:5], чтоб оставить только нужное

Comment: Попробую найти, но не обещаю что получится :)

Comment: @dog3000 первые пять символов - [:5]

Comment: не понимаю, это мы обратились к чему [:5], к времени, и отсекаем лишний текст "Live streamsbet365bwin", верно? Применил код print(tr_time.text[:5]) консоль осталась пустой, почему так получилось?

Comment: @dog3000 [:5] - это срез, в данном случае строки, скорее не отсекаем "Live streamsbet365bwin", а берем только "16:00"... тут print сработает, если tr_time будет не None, проверьте

Comment: все понял! Благодарю!